# SQL query to suggest some resources to a request by options selected

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to suggest to my user's some resources based on their request.

Here is my 5 tables for resources and their options and request and selected options

```
Resource     res_opt_junc    Options    req_opt_junc    Request
---------    ------------    -------    ------------    --------
Res_id       res_id          opt_id     req_id          Req_id
             opt_id                     opt_id
```

I'm getting request and selected options from user and I want resources that can satisfy user selected options in request.

To simplify, I want resources that at least have all of request selected options.

Some sample data should be like this

```
Resource      res_opt_junc       Options            req_opt_junc     Request
----------    ------------      ------------       -------------    --------
id name       res_id  opt_id    opt_id   name      req_id opt_id     req_id
1 class1      1        1        1       internet     1       1         1
              1        2        2       projector    1       2          

2 class2      2        1                             2       1          2
```

so here is some data ,
for example if user needed a class that must have option 1(internet) and 2(projector) i need to suggest class1 but not class2 that only have one of options user selected for request number 1

Comment: How are you passing the selected options?

Comment: selected Options goes into req_opt_junc (junction) table .

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and expected result?

Comment: yes , were should i post them , should i edit the main question ?

Comment: Yes, edit the question.

Comment: i`m trying to put sample data but i`m not comfortable with the editor

Comment: Just try it, maybe someone will come and edit it for you.

Comment: How are you passing the parameters? Do you have a stored procedure that accepts `request_id` and `option_id`s?

Comment: yes i have stored procedure but just taking request id , because i toked option_id s before from the user that submitted the request . and here is i`m trying to suggest to someone else (like admin) to attach a suitable resource to request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit after OP's comment:

This now become Relational Division with Remainder. Here is one way to solve this:

```
SELECT r.id, r.name
FROM res_opt_junc ro
INNER JOIN(
    SELECT opt_id
    FROM res_opt_junc
    WHERE res_id = @req_id
)t
    ON t.opt_id = ro.opt_id
INNER JOIN Resource r
    ON r.id = ro.res_id
GROUP BY r.id, r.name
HAVING
    COUNT(t.opt_id) = (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM res_opt_junc
        WHERE res_id = @req_id
    )
```

Another solution:

```
DECLARE @req_id INT = 1

DECLARE @opts TABLE(opt_id INT PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO @opts
    SELECT opt_id
    FROM req_opt_junc
    WHERE req_id = @req_id

SELECT r.*
FROM (
    SELECT
        res_id, cnt = COUNT(DISTINCT opt_id)
    FROM res_opt_junc
    WHERE opt_id IN(SELECT opt_id FROM @opts)
    GROUP BY res_id
)a
INNER JOIN Resource r
    ON r.id = a.res_id
WHERE
    a.cnt = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @opts)
```

---

I believe this is a [**Relational Division with no Remainder (RDNR)**](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/high-performance-relational-division-in-sql-server/) problem.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e1020/1/0)

Here is one way to solve this:

```
DECLARE @req_id INT = 1

DECLARE @opts TABLE(opt_id INT PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO @opts
    SELECT opt_id
    FROM req_opt_junc
    WHERE req_id = @req_id

SELECT r.*
FROM (
    SELECT
        res_id, cnt = COUNT(DISTINCT opt_id)
    FROM res_opt_junc
    WHERE opt_id IN(SELECT opt_id FROM @opts)
    GROUP BY res_id
)a
INNER JOIN Resource r
    ON r.id = a.res_id
WHERE
    a.cnt = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @opts)
    AND a.cnt = (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM res_opt_junc
        WHERE res_id = a.res_id
    )
```

---

If you don't want to use table variable:

```
SELECT r.*
FROM (
    SELECT
        res_id, cnt = COUNT(DISTINCT opt_id)
    FROM res_opt_junc
    WHERE opt_id IN(
        SELECT opt_id
        FROM req_opt_junc
        WHERE req_id = @req_id
    )
    GROUP BY res_id
)a
INNER JOIN Resource r
    ON r.id = a.res_id
WHERE
    a.cnt = (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM req_opt_junc
        WHERE req_id = @req_id
    )
    AND a.cnt = (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM res_opt_junc
        WHERE res_id = a.res_id
    )
```

Comment: Thank man , i just test your query and it`s work , i`ll test it a little more and  i inform you later

Comment: No problem. Be sure to read the article. Also, use `'` instead of ` for apostrophe.

Comment: sorry man but this not worked , i dont need an exact match , i need resources that satisfy the request and they maybe have more options but at least they have the options requested

Comment: @MTaher, See my update. Your problem not becomes RDWR instead of RDNR.

Comment: thank you for your attention and time now when i execute the new query it say's , error :Column 'Resource.location' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Put it in the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: or use `SELECT r.id, r.name` instead of `r.*`.

Comment: error gone , but no result showing when executing query but it work on [link]http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1c901/5

Comment: thank man table variable solution worked , but why the first one work on sqlfiddle sample and not in my database ?

Comment: @MTaher, check your data. There must be something different.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT res_id FROM req_opt_junc AS rqoj
LEFT JOIN res_opt_junc AS rsoj ON rsoj.opt_id = rqoj.opt_id
WHERE rqoj.req_id = "request id goes here"
AND rqoj.opt = "option id goes here"
```

Comment: thanks but i tried this before it shows every resource that have one of request`s options , i need resources that have every user selected options in request.

Comment: @M Taher so are you taking two inputs? one is request id and the other is option id ?

Comment: @MTaher, again, sample data and expected result would help clarify your question/

Comment: i`m taking one request id and 1 or many Options_id that i store them in Request and req_opt_junc tables , so that i can retrive option`s belong to every request any time

Comment: Well, based on information above, you have to have both 'request id' and 'option id' at the same time in order to select correct class from Resource table

Comment: i think i have option id s for both my request and resource in my junction tables , haven`t i ?